# Why isn't my PrintWriter writing out to by ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, servlets, java-io, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a `HttpServletResponseWrapper` that overrides `getOutputStream()` with a simple `ByteArrayOutputStream`. But whenever I pass the wrapped response, nothing ever gets written to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

What I am doing wrong?

### The wrapper

```
private static class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream responseBytes;

    public ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        responseBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return responseBytes.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() { return new ServletOutputStream() {
        private WriteListener writeListener;
        @Override
        public boolean isReady() { return true; }
        @Override
        public void setWriteListener(WriteListener writeListener) {
            this.writeListener = writeListener;
        }
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            responseBytes.write(b);
            Optional.ofNullable(writeListener).ifPresent(WriteListener::notify);
        }
    };}

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() { return new PrintWriter(getOutputStream()); }
}
```

### Passing around the wrapped response

```
@Override
public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // create a new byte array outputstream and writer that uses the outputstream

    // create a new response wrapper and 'hi-jack' the outputstream
    ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(response);
    view.render(model, request, responseWrapper);
    byte[] htmlBytes = responseWrapper.getBytes();

    if (htmlBytes.length == 0) {
        throw new PhantomPdfException(
            "The rendered HTML response from the template was empty. "
            // this is ALWAYS empty
        );
    }
    // more code...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `view.render()` uses `getWriter()` and the (buffering) `PrintWriter` does not get flushed?

Comment: Don't create a new output stream and writer each time the method is called; you don't necessarily know how often these methods will get called by the render code.  Aside from the flush issue halfbit has already pointed out, it is possible that the code calls `getWriter()` multiple times, which would cause you to lose any data that had been written earlier.

Comment: @halfbit flushing worked. you're my hero. post some answer for some more rep!